# Python return unique elements combinations

Tags: python

If I have a list like this:

```
ls = [['water', 'chips', 'pie'], ['soda', 'nuts', 'cake'], ['water', 'chips', 'cake']]
```

Let's say the list falls into categories of "drink", "snack", and "desert". I want to return all of the unique element combinations for "drink" and "snack". The list should return this:

```
ls = [['water', 'chips'], ['soda', 'nuts']]
```

It would not return the third list, because `water` and `chips` already exist in another list in `ls`.

Comment: add some input, expected output and what data and row are

Comment: Provide a sample of your data

Comment: You mean a loop through the values in each row? Like using a nested loop?

Comment: see above edit. hope that clarifies.

Comment: What the logic is? How could you explain the process leading us to get the result you provided?

Comment: The new ls[0] is not unique...

Comment: pick the first 2 elements of any one of your individual list, but only count them once?

Comment: Pick only the unique combinations of any two list indices, in this case, the first two. I edited my "edit" above a little bit, maybe it makes a little more sense now.

Comment: Data structures usually contain elements or members. An index is the actual index, not the thing it refers to.  In the expression ls[1] where ls is a list, the index is 1, what you get back is the element. Keeping the distinction clear will make your questions a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clear up the terminology. Edits reflected above.

Comment: so picking row[0] and row[1] is given specified by parameters?  could be row[1] and row[2]?

Comment: Yes, or row[0] and row[2]

Comment: You'll also get more useful answers if you describe what you're trying to do more concretely. The bulk of beginner questions of this type seem like they're about rube-golberg-like contraptions of lists, loops, filters, sets (case in point, your original example has an unnecessary loop and list) and most of them can in fact be answered by making a data structure that will give you the views of the data that you want and then filling it with a single pass over the data or even as the data is coming in from input like a file or a db.

Comment: The inclusion of the loop was deliberate as I do need to total certain values, I just didn't include the totaling as it was irrelevant to the question. But point well-taken with regard to concrete data and data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>>> ls = [['water', 'chips', 'pie'], ['soda', 'nuts', 'cake'], ['water', 'chips', 'cake']]

>>> item_position = { "drink": 0,
        "snack": 1,
       "desert": 2}

>>> set((x[item_position['drink']], x[item_position['snack']]) for x in ls)
{('soda', 'nuts'), ('water', 'chips')}
```

Here, i am creating a `item_position` dict which gives the position of food item type in the inner list. 
Then, i create a tuple of required items i.e. `drink` and `snack` here and apply `set` operator to filter the duplicates.

The benefit of this is that you can just pass in the item type name without worrying about its index . Also you can change the number of items   of the inner list to be used while preparing the tuple.

Comment: The tuple is created by way of enclosing `x[item_position['drink']` and `x[item_position['snack']` in parenthesis, correct?

Comment: Is there a way to return the entire item, and not just the unique elements?

Comment: Yes, tuple is created by enclosing it in paranthesis.

Comment: You can remove `set()` and apply list comprehension to get the entire item i.e. `[(x[item_position['drink']], x[item_position['snack']]) for x in ls]
` which returns `[('water', 'chips'), ('soda', 'nuts'), ('water', 'chips')]
`.

Answer (score 1):

You want the unique values for each list, it seems. You are already half-way there, since you have a set of all unique values in `unqBuilding`.

```
unique_per_row = [list(set(r).difference(unqBuilding))
                  for r in row]
```

The above will generate a list with a list of the items in each row that only appear in that row.

The `difference` method of a set takes another set and returns a new set with the items that appear only in the first set. It's easier to understand with a Venn diagram. In the diagram below, the equivalent of `right.difference(left)` is highlighted in red.

[image: Complement]

Comment: Ok, I answered before the edit... whatever. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, my comment was just a response to "I'm not sure what you mean by 'unique combination values'.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Tired of people downvoting without feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

pos0 and pos1 would have to be variables to a function, along with the list itself, but you get the idea.

```
pos0 = 0
pos1 = 2

ls = [['water', 'chips', 'pie'], ['soda', 'nuts', 'cake'], ['water', 'chips', 'cake']]

s = set()
for row in ls:
    #cant hash a list, tuple it

    tu = (row[pos0], row[pos1])

    s.add(tu)
#untuple the set's contents back to lists
print [list(tu) for tu in s]
```

output:pos 0, 1

```
[['soda', 'nuts'], ['water', 'chips']]
```

pos 0, 2

```
[['soda', 'cake'], ['water', 'cake'], ['water', 'pie']]
```

Comment: Without slicing, how can I select two elements, for example ones with indices 3 and 5

Comment: row[pos0].  that's just 1 element.